# Get $breadcrumb variable in toolbar.tpl.php - Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming, drupal-templates

I want to use $breadcrumb variable in toolbar.tpl.php (administration toolbar).
page.tpl.php processed after toolbar.tpl.php so

hook_preprocess_page(){} and hook_preprocess_toolbar(){} useless

how can i do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can build the breadcrumb yourself using a combination of [`drupal_get_breadcrumb()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_get_breadcrumb/7) and [`theme_breadcrumb()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_breadcrumb/7), like so:

```
$breadcrumb = theme('breadcrumb', array('breadcrumb' => drupal_get_breadcrumb()));
```

Comment: this work but I wonder that. is that possible. Passing page Level Variables to page_top level for example page.tpl.php to toolbar.tpl.php.

Comment: Not really, no. The variables for a theme function/template are built up when that theme/template is pre-processed. These values aren't stored anywhere, just passed through to theme/template. As you say, page.tpl.php is built later on in the process so those variables simply haven't been created yet